# Finding the correct aspect ratio from image

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, digital-image-processing, datum, cesium

I'm trying to put an image over my map.

I know the correct bounding box of it, but when I load it, I see it doesn't fit correctly in the map.

Just for curiosity, I cut a piece of map of same region from OSM and use Photoshop to position the borders of the image until it fits over the background OSM.

This is the result:

[image]

After all, the corners are EXACTLY where they must be (using the OSM map as reference): in the coordinates I put in Cesium to load the image (left/bottom is LON -90, LAT -70 and right/top is LON 0, LAT 20), but in Cesium although the corners are in same position, the map from the image does not fit. This is the result:

[image]

You can browse it here: http://cmabreu.com.br/blankcesium/

and here is the PNG I'm trying to fit in map: http://cmabreu.com.br/c21090900.png

and the code:

```
    var baseOsmProvider = new Cesium.OpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
        url : 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/'
    });             
    
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer',{
        timeline: false,
        baseLayerPicker: false,
        skyAtmosphere: false,
        fullscreenButton : false,
        sceneMode: Cesium.SceneMode.SCENE2D,
        geocoder : false,
        homeButton : false,
        infoBox : false,
        skyBox : false,
        sceneModePicker : false,
        selectionIndicator : false,
        navigationHelpButton : false,
        requestRenderMode : true,
        imageryProvider: baseOsmProvider,
        shouldAnimate : true,
        contextOptions: {
            requestWebgl2: true
        }               
    });
    var scene = viewer.scene;
    var layers = scene.imageryLayers;
    
    layers.addImageryProvider(
      new Cesium.SingleTileImageryProvider({
        url: "../c21090900.png",
        rectangle: Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(-90, -70, 0, 20), // west, south, east, north
      })
    );
```

so what can I do to make the image fits over the map?

GDAL info from the PNG image:

```
Driver: PNG/Portable Network Graphics
Files: c21090900.jpg.png
Size is 1455, 1936
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 1936.0)
Upper Right ( 1455.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 1455.0, 1936.0)
Center      (  727.5,  968.0)
Band 1 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

... and from the TIF I created from it:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: c21090900.tif
Size is 1455, 1936
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-90.000000000000000,20.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.061855670103093,-0.046487603305785)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -90.0000000,  20.0000000) ( 90d 0' 0.00"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  ( -90.0000000, -70.0000000) ( 90d 0' 0.00"W, 70d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right (   0.0000000,  20.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (   0.0000000, -70.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E, 70d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      ( -45.0000000, -25.0000000) ( 45d 0' 0.00"W, 25d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=1455x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

I can use GDAL and Imagemagick but the tools you give must be headless because this is an automatic process and I can't use Photoshop every time ....

**EDIT AFTER JONASV ANSWER**

As JonasV answer, I've applied `gdal_translate -tr 0.05 -0.05 c21090912.png c21090912-sqr.png` but it not work. The error was:

*Input file size is 1455, 1936
ERROR 5: The -tr option was used, but there's no geotransform or it is
rotated.  This configuration is not supported.*

So I think:

"*- Humm... what if I do this in the final TIF file? It have geoinformation after all..*"

It produces no error, but the final result was the same. Th image still not fiting over the map..

This is the GDALINFO of the "pixel-squarized" TIF:

```
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-90.000000000000000,20.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.050000000000000,-0.050000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -90.0000000,  20.0000000) ( 90d 0' 0.00"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  ( -90.0000000, -70.0000000) ( 90d 0' 0.00"W, 70d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right (   0.0000000,  20.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (   0.0000000, -70.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E, 70d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      ( -45.0000000, -25.0000000) ( 45d 0' 0.00"W, 25d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=1800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 2 Block=1800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 3 Block=1800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
Band 4 Block=1800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

**EDIT 2**
Well... I've received a KML file from same source of the image Im using for test and it is working very well over the map. This makes me very curious and I've decided to open the KML to see the image inside it.

I'm surprised to see the image was somehow redimensioned by the source creator to this version:

[image]

You can see the latitude scale compressed to equidistant causing some distortion in the pixels, but I think this was not made by a image editor because seems more like a reprojection.

Here is the problematic image just for comparation ( not same DATA, but same IMAGE. The image content data may vary because it is not my concern, just its SIZE):

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is, that the pixels are not square in the geotiff (`Pixel Size = (0.061855670103093,-0.046487603305785)`) and since I think you can't specify a geoTransform in Cesium, the png ends up distorted.

I don't know much about Cesium, but as far as I see it you have a few options:

1. Use [gdal2tiles](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html) to build a Tile Map Service which you should be able to directly load with `Cesium.TileMapServiceImageryProvider`
2. Use the `-tr` option of [gdal_translate](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-tr) to output the raster with square pixels

Comment: Thanks Jonas. gdal2tiles was my first try and the result was the same.  But I think like you about the pixel size. Just not told in my question to not lead anyone. I'm happy to see the first answer touching this. Well... I think my last hope is in the gdal_translate.  Lets try it.

Comment: Must comment this image came from a JPG with White background. The transparency was given with imagemagick and then I've got the PNG that I turned into the TIF using the botton and left coordinates found in image as bbox.  The projection used to draw the map in the picture is Mercator.

Comment: So Jonas... in wich of steps above you think I can apply The "Pixel Squarator" ( gdal_translate -tr )?

Comment: I would run the png through gdal_translate again, you can still output a png, but set the target resolution to something square. Something like this might work: `gdal_translate -tr 0.05 -0.05 in_non_square.png out_square.png`

Comment: It not work Jonas. Please see my edit in the question. Changing image pixel or the image height does not change anything.

Comment: I've added more useful information. Can you help?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm now also out of ideas